# Cloud9 Code 127, cannot run server, preview works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide, cloud9, c9.io

I cannot seem to get my server running via run button but the preview works and command works.

Steps I did to get to this point:

Started a blank cloud 9 instance and ran the following commands:

```
$ mkdir myapp

$ cd myapp

$ rvm use ruby-2.3.0@myapp --ruby-version --create

$ gem install rails

$ rails new .

$ rake -T

$ rails server -p $PORT -b $IP
```

At this point the preview works and I can access https://[workspace]-[user].c9users.io. However, if I press run then click CWD and select the myapp folder I get the following error:

```
myapp/Gemfile: No such file or directory
```

The command that shows up in the run panel is `myapp/Gemfile` I've also tried to use `Gemfiel` when changing CWD to the myapp folder and the myapp/Gemfile prior to changing cwd.

Is the run button just a way of running the command `rails server -p $PORT -b $IP` if so then as long as that command works and I can access the site, then there's no purpose to pressing run other than to save typing?

Comment: If you go to your app directory, and run `rails s -p $PORT -b $IP` works fine?

Comment: Indeed. Just pressing the Run button doesn't seem to work which is why I also ask is the run button just a short cut to typing the command? If so then I guess I don't really need it.

Comment: The Run button is one way to run your app. If your app is running via command line, you willl like to use the Run button because if an easy/fast way to get your app running.

Comment: Give a few minutes to post an aswer that might be good for you.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm an idiot. but I think I figured it out.
The default when you press run for whatever reason the command is set to myapp/Gemfile and so it wasn't running because that shouldn't be the command. The instruction says I need to change my CWD, but didn't indicate I needed to change the command as well to `rails s -p $PORT -b $IP`

Comment: When you use the Run button C9 will try to run you current file (not the file), that is why you need to especify what is the app that you want to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first you need to consider, is that your app is running without problems (run `rails s -p $PORT -b $IP` without problems).
If that is the case, is really simple to set your <kbd>Run</kbd> to run your app.

First in your menu go to **Run > Run Configuration > Run new configuration**

[image]

Then It will open a run configuration tab, where you need to set your "Currente Working Directory" by clicking on <kbd>CWD</kbd>

[image]

And finally, you need to type your command (in the command textbox) to start your rails app, something like:

```
rails s -p $PORT -b $IP
```

With that you will get your app running with the <kbd>Run</kbd> button.

Source: [docs.c9](https://docs.c9.io/docs/run-an-application)

Comment: It was that last step that wasn't quite clear from the docs to me - putting in the rails command into the command box. It seemed like it wanted a file from the docs but I misinterpreted. Thank you for your clarifications.